# Pentaho Carte How to pass parameter in Job Level

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am currently trying to develop simple parameter passing process using Pentaho and execute the job from web (Carte). I have a transformation and also a job. I have successfully pass the parameter if I execute it directly through transformation.  http://cluster:cluster@localhost:8080/kettle/executeTrans/?trans=/data-integration/PENTAHO_JOB/test_var.ktr&testvar=1234567

[image: transformation level]

however, when I try to put the transformation in a Job and execute it in job level, I could not get the parameter **testvar** now even though I can run it successfully. i also found out that there is no **Get Variable** function in Job level. I wonder if I can get the parameter **testvar** by executing from job level in Carte?

[image: Job Level]

http://cluster:cluster@localhost:8080/kettle/executeJob/?job=/data-integration/PENTAHO_JOB/test_var.kjb&testvar=1234567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Raspi Surya :
Its working for me . You need to set the variable in parameter at job level. I used the below URL.
http://localhost:8080/kettle/executeJob/?job=C:\Data-Integration\carte-testing.kjb&file_name=C:\Data-Integration\file1.csv

See the attached SS[image: CartewithParameter]

Comment: hi, thank you very much, can you tell me which screen is that? is it on Run Option screen?  and which pentaho version are you using?

Comment: I got it, thank you very much... so I need to right click on the job window and set the parameter right there. Thank you!